# Click on button based on text in div class selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have one `<div>` class having `<a>` tag and `<h3>` tags and the same `<div>`. I just wanted to click `<a>` of that div class based on `<h3>` text.

As per below example, div class name is "**product eq-height**" having `<h3>` tag who has some text **"Applet Iphone 5S"** if this result found then click on `<a>` class named "**select-device-button**".

But this div class comes multiple times with different H3 text on the page.

```
<div class="product eq-height" style="padding-bottom: 0px ! important; min-height: 329px;">
                    <h3 class="h4">Apple Iphone 5S</h3>

                    <input name="productModel" value="Apple Iphone 5S" type="hidden">
                    <div class="subtitle">
                      <span>Apple</span>
                    </div>
                    <a class="select-device-button" href="javascript:void(0);">
                      <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" class="prod-img-lrg lazyloaded" data-src="https://vgeco-oat1.vodafone.com/images/Iphone 5S.jpg" src="https://vgeco-oat1.vodafone.com/images/Iphone 5S.jpg"> <noscript><img alt="" src="https://vgeco-oat1.vodafone.com/images/Iphone 5S.jpg"&gt;</noscript>
                      </div></a>

                      <div class="info">
                        <div class="inner">
                          <ul class="cost">
                            <li><b>Total cost</b>
                            </li>


                            <li class="price">£ 300.00</li>
                          </ul>


                          <ul class="cost">
                            <li><b>My cost</b>
                            </li>

                                                                                                                <li class="price">£ 106.99</li>                            
                          </ul>
                        </div>


                        <div class="cta">
                          <a class="btn btn-sml select-device-button" href="javascript:void(0);">Select</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="co-link-wrap txt-center">
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: How many h3 tags are there in your div??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is one possible XPath expression :**

```
//div[@class='product eq-height' and h3='Apple Iphone 5S']/a[@class='select-device-button']
```

**explanation :**

- **`//div[@class='product eq-height' and h3='Apple Iphone 5S']`** : The above XPath will first find `div` element where `class` attribute value equals `"product eq-height"` and has child `h3` with value equals `"Apple Iphone 5S"`.
- **`/a[@class='select-device-button']`** : Then from found `div` elements, the XPath returns child element `a` where `class` attribute value equals `"select-device-button"`.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly you want to find an `a` element through certain `div` and `h3`, if yes then it you can do it pretty straightforward like so:

`//div[h3[text()="Apple Iphone 5S"]]/a[@class="select-device-button"]`

You are looking for `div` element that has certain `h3` element and from there it's very easy to find the next element you want by using it's class attribute or any other that you need/want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you have structure like..

```
<div>
<h3>Xyz</h3>
<a>Something there</a>
</div>
```

and you want to click on `<a>` tag when `h3` is clicked

try to give a data attribute to `h3`  same to the id of `a` and then when user click on `h3`and get that data attribute in java script (`attr("data")`) and then click it through java script